# How to find a trusted average for a given population?

Tags: confidence-interval, standard-deviation, standard-error, mean

I am working on the following table:

```
Weight (W)  Rating  Weighted Score (WS)
0.10           3    0,30
0.11           4    0,44
0.10           3    0,30
0.12           3    0,36
0.07           2    0,14
0.11           2    0,22
0.08           1    0,08
0.12           1    0,12
0.10           2    0,20
0.09           2    0,18
1.00           -    2,34
```

The WS is calculated by multiplying Rating with W. In the last line, the total sum of W's is `1.00`, while for WS is `2,34`.

What I am willing to know, is how can I evaluate if `2,34` is good or bad, in other words if it is above or below average? I was told that an average value for WS would be `2.5` but not why. Is there any other statistic measure, such as Standard Deviation, Standard Error, Confidence Intervals, that can help me make sense of the data, or to determine which average should I trust?

Comment: It doesn't look like multiplication. The first row of data doesn't follow the rule.

Comment: @kevin012 You are right, I edited question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are showing here is the weighted average of $Rating$, potentially for one subject. In order to decide whether this is above or below average, you need a sample of subjects over which you will do the same calculation and then you can calculate the average of the weighted averages of all subjects to get the sample's mean. Then, you will be able to compare any other subject's weighted average to that number.

Let $R$ be an $n*k$ matrix, of $n$ results for $k$ subjects, $w$ your weights vector with the importance of each result and $1_{n*1}$, $1_{k*1}$ are $n*1$ and $k*1$ vectors respectively, with all elements equal to 1. Then the weighted average of each subject is equal to the vector $r$

$$r=[\operatorname{diag}(w)R]^T1_{n*1}$$

and the average of the weighted averages of all subjects $\mu_r$ is
$$\mu_r=\frac{r^T1_{k*1}}{k}$$

Comment: So say I change the Rating values a couple of times and calculate new sums for WS. Will the average value of those new sums, be the number I am looking for? Is there any statistical measure to do so 'automatically'?

Comment: I don't know the context of your problem. However, yes, if $Rating$ is a matrix where each column is a different subject, you can get the weighted average from that as the sample's weighted mean. Assuming automatically means algebraically, I am amending my answer to include that